# Rename the git-subtree squashed commit

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm trying to add a subtree to my project. And it works just as it should. But the remote I am pushing to has a pre-receive hook that validates if a commit has a JIRA number in front of it. This is unfortunate because when subtree squashes the history, it removes the previous messages and leaves a generic "Squashed  'prefix' content from..." message.

Alas, though I'd like to simply remove this asinine hook, I have to somehow work around it. Here's what my tree looks like:

```
*   90285a0edac Merge commit '4c2e69861591fada9f5c752857ec871f84adf145' as 'prefix'
|\  
| * 4c2e6986159 Squashed 'prefix/' content from commit 4ffbd12 
* 34f9e457b68 JIRA-1234: Add some feature
```

The subtree works as expected, but I need to rename commit 4c2e6986... to include a JIRA number in front of it to circumvent a hook on the remote.

I am able to easily rename the Merge commit using `rebase -i -p`, but I'm unsure how to rename the Squash commit.

Comment: I hit this exact situation, did you figure this out @OP?

Comment: @Samar unfortunately, no :( I just removed the hook because it was getting on my nerves.